# Fastlane: using GYM having provisionning profile set in xconfig files

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane

I have read https://codesigning.guide/ but decided to not use this solution to store my provisionning profiles, but rather store them in the git of each project.

For my project, I have specified my provisionning profiles in my xconfig files (using PROVISIONING_PROFILE = ).
I have these schemes perfectly working in Xcode
- staging-dev
- staging-adhoc

When Using gym() in my Fastfile I set my workspace and scheme like so:

```
gym(
    workspace: xcworkspace_file,
    scheme: scheme_adhoc_name,
    clean: true
)
```

*Note: xcworkspace_file and scheme_adhoc_name are variable set before.*

It should be enough specifying my workspace and scheme, but when using fastlane, console says the following:

```
[17:14:09]: -----------------
[17:14:09]: --- Step: gym ---
[17:14:09]: -----------------
[17:14:09]: Found more than one provisioning profile in the project directory:
1. AdHoc_com.xxx.ddd.mobileprovision
2. Development_com.xxx.ddd.mobileprovision
```

If I select 1 or 2, it works but this shouldn't be asked because provisionning profile is already in xconfig used by my scheme.

Plus, I don't want to set ENV["PROVISIONING_PROFILE_TARGET1"] nor gym(provisioning_profile_path: ) (which is deprecated).

Why couldn't I simply use my values set in xconfig files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you get is because of the auto-detection of the provisioning profile in the current directory.

You can either not have any provisioning profiles in the current directory, or just specify one using in your `Fastfile`, so that you don't get asked.

Comment: Moved my provisionning profiles in a new folder, works perfectly fine now, thanks (and thanks for fastlane btw)

Comment: @eter good to hear, feel free to mark this reply as working solution